# Doctrine ORM ManyToOne Inverse not working

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, many-to-one

I have a bidirectional manytoone-onetomany relationship that is only working in one direction, can someone please help. I have tried to strip down the example to the minimum code required for clarity.

The Question entity can have many Answer entities.

Question Entity

```
class CwEmployeeQuestion
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cw_employee_answers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeAnswer", mappedBy="cw_employee_question")
    */
    protected $cw_employee_answers;

    /**
     * Get CwEmployeeAnswer
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
    */
    public function getCwEmployeeAnswer()
    {
        return $this->cw_employee_answers;
    }
}
```

Answer entity

```
class CwEmployeeAnswer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Many CwEmployeeAnswer have One CwEmployeeQuestion.
     * 
     * @var \Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeQuestion $cw_employee_question
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeQuestion", inversedBy="cw_employee_answer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cw_employee_question", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $cw_employee_question;

    /**
     * Set $cw_employee_question
     *
     * @param   \Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeQuestion $cw_employee_question
     * @return  CwEmployeeAnswer
     */
    public function setCwEmployeeQuestion(?\Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeQuestion $cw_employee_question = null): self
    {
        $this->cw_employee_question = $cw_employee_question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get $cw_employee_question
     *
     * @return \Fitchek\Entity\Corporate\CwEmployeeQuestion
     */
    public function getCwEmployeeQuestion(): ?CwEmployeeQuestion
    {
        return $this->cw_employee_question;
    }

    /**
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param   JSON                $json, the request JSON to create a new CwEmployeeAnswer
     * @return  CwEmployeeAnswer    the newly created CwEmployeeAnswer
     */
    public function createFromData($json, $cw_employee_question = null)
    {
        $this->setCwEmployeeQuestion($cw_employee_question);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I try the direction answer->question, it works fine and returns to me a list of answers with their associated question as part of the JSON. For example:

```
[
  { "id": 1
    "name": "answer 1",
    "question" : {
      "name": "question 1"
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

However when query the other direction to get all questions with their answers as part of the return JSON the array of questions comes back as null. For example:

```
[
  { "id": 1
    "name": "question 1",
    "answers": null
  }
  ...
]
```

When what I would like to see is:

```
[
  { "id": 1
    "name": "question 1",
    "answers" : [
      {
        "name": "answer 1"
      },
     {
        "name": "answer 2"
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ok. Probably just a typo.
Try to use `inversedBy="cw_employee_answers"` (plural as $cw_employee_answers) instead of `inversedBy="cw_employee_answer"`
It should work.